# Invisible software updates list in Software Updater

Tags: update-manager

Today I received an update notification for three updates but update manager doesn't say what updates are they.

[image: No details of updates]

Does anyone have a clue what this is about? How am I to check what is to be updated?

Comment: What does the terminal say? sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Few days back i got the same error, so i did upgrade from terminal ( sudo apt-get upgrade ).

Comment: Do we have a bug report for this?  If not, someone should create one.  I didn't think to capture a screen shot, but you have one here that would be good to include in a bug report.

Comment: I just opened Bug #1211511 for this issue.  I was able to grab a an apport log and a screenshot of the problem.  Please confirm this bug if you are impacted by it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1211511

Comment: Could it be that the upgrade-able packages are libraries and other "system" packages, and therefore hidden? (this could be done to confuse the user less about the updated packages, (s)he would probably only care if "Firefox" is updated?)

Comment: The same thing here and it only started happening in the last couple of weeks.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this problem after upgrading to 18.04. Preparatory to `sudo apt-get upgrade` as noted above, I did

```
 sudo apt autoremove
```

That resolved the problem for me and 'revealed' what updates were available for download. Almost half-a-gig clogging up the works.

Comment: Good.  Did you also file a bug?

Answer (score 4):

Don’t worry! I have been through this. To clarify that I did that in terminal with

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and it listed the outputs. Only 3 upgrades will be there if I remember correctly.

Comment: Even if that solved the issue, it **has** to be reported as a bug. Help the whole community!

Comment: @Lucio , I agree with your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Check for an orphaned `update-manager` process that may be causing the empty Software Updater window.

```
pgrep -fl update-manager
```

You can kill all `update-manager` processes with:

```
pkill -f update-manager
```

Run `apt list --upgradable` in the terminal to see a list of packages that can be upgraded.