# Software Updater is empty in Xubuntu 13.04

Tags: xubuntu, software-updater

I have just installed xubuntu 13.04 on an old laptop, and once a day I get the notification that updates are available.

But When I open *Software Updater*, it shows that there are some updates, but the list is empty:
[image]

What do I need to do to see the names of the packages that have updates?

There are a few similar question already, but they do not solve my issue.

- [Software updater shows no details about the updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331305/software-updater-shows-no-details-about-the-updates) suggests reinstalling `gtk3-engines-oxygen` but that package is not installed, so it cannot be removed.
- [Invisible updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331680/invisible-updates) talks about apt-get upgrade. I have tried that, but it does not solve the issue.

Comment: This looks like the same problem as http://askubuntu.com/q/331680/54298.

Comment: @hexafraction Doing that does not solve my issue.