# 13.04 software updater blank

Tags: software-updater

Software updater says I have 7 updates, but both the 'details' and 'technical description' areas are BLANK! I don't want to install unknowns. Ubuntu Studio 13.4. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invisible software updates list in Software Updater](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331680/invisible-software-updates-list-in-software-updater)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I didn't do anything, just rebooted the system few times and everything worked fine. If the problem persist try this:

1) Open a terminal
2) Type sudo -i
3) Type your password
4) apt-get update
5) apt-get autoclean
6) Reboot your system and try again.

Hope that worked for you :) Don't give up, sometimes Ubuntu fix the problems along the time without user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening to a bunch of people. This is [Launchpad bug 1211511](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1211511). I ran

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to update from the command line in a terminal.