# Ubuntu 20.04 prompts for software updates but doesn't update

Tags: 20.04, update-manager

For the past few weeks, my OS prompts me for available software updates but does nothing.

[image: Screenshot of the update window]

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this similar issue :

[blank software updater window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514024/small-blank-software-updater-window)

It says that it can be caused by an orphaned `update-manager` process.

Lets hope it can solve your problem.

Regards