# How can I solve the problem of an empty window for Software Updater?

Tags: updates, 16.04, update-manager

My Ubuntu 16.04 only displays an empty white window for the Software Updater:

[image]

I can run `apt-get update` without a problem:

```
...
Fetched 94,5 kB in 5s (17,1 kB/s)                  
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Dis you try if a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` maybe solves this? Otherwise you might need to file a bug report.

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS but, in my case, updating via terminal did not solve it. 
@orschiro do you know which packages where updated in you system when this bug was solved?

Comment: @Prolix: unfortunately not. I am sorry. Maybe you can report this as a bug then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invisible updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331680/invisible-updates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, run and update via terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) to fix this, you can do this with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```