# Unetbootin has no GUI on Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: usb, unetbootin

I want to make the switch to Antergos. When opening Unetbootin, I can't open it successfully.

Here is what happens when I open UNetbootin from Terminal:

```
$ sudo unetbootin
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x164
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0xc0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x2800010
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x2800010
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x2800010
```

[image]

Is this a known issue? Can I fix this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Did you open it from a terminal? What messages appeared there?

Comment: Is http://askubuntu.com/questions/775517/how-can-i-solve-the-problem-of-an-empty-window-for-software-updater of any help?

Comment: ok edited! the other comment didnt help because those commands ugrade the system. they dont fix the blank box @DKBose

Comment: @lolreppeatlol, Avoid using `sudo` with graphic tools, you could use `gksu`, see why [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus). Could you post output of  `ls -l .Xauthority` and `which unetbootin`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First uninstall your current version of unetbootin, then use official unetbootin [page](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html) to install using ppa instead of deb files. If fails then try opening it from launcher instead of terminal.

Comment: Wow, it worked! Should have thought of that. :P Thanks. I'll give the bounty later when possible.

Comment: OK! no problem.

Comment: I try in ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but not works.

Comment: this answer would be improved by adding how to `uninstall your current version of unetbootin`

Answer (score 45):

This is a known issue.

As a workaround that does not require reinstalling unetbootin, you can run this command:

```
sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 unetbootin
```

What the above command does is disable shared memory access for running this Qt based application, allowing it to work properly on GNOME.

The PPA source for unetbootin in the accepted answer includes the prefix to disable shared memory access in the default run command so that launching it from the GUI shortcut just works without any hassle: https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Source of answer:
https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/issues/67

Comment: QT_X11_NO_MITSHM didn't work for me (on ArchLinux). However, knowing the problem is with X11 extensions, I solved the problem by "ssh -Y localhost" as a tunneled X11 connection doesn't support them.

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for your comment, @the-it-philosopher.

Comment: This worked for me whereas the updating the PPA did not.. Thanks!

Comment: Installed from the PPA, got the grey screen, but this works.  18.04 desktop.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the `Exec` property in `unetbootin.desktop`:

> Exec=/usr/bin/xdg-su -c /usr/bin/unetbootin

and created file `/usr/bin/unetbootin` with the bash script:

> #!/bin/bash
>   QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 /usr/sbin/unetbootin

then made it exetutable:

> sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/unetbootin

and now when I run `Unetbootin` from my application overview it launches normally with GUI.

Comment: But the  file `/usr/bin/unetbootin` already exists, **that is the binary**, there seems something mixed up here. Own files should reside under `/usr/local/sbin`

Answer (score 2):

Since Ubuntu 17.10  wayland is the default x server, the program that manages access to the graphic devices drivers, `xhosts` allows users to connect to those drivers.

Since `sudo` doesn't have an active session nor it's allow to access the server, `unetbootin` cannot create an instance of it's GUI.

Once you run that you give `sudo` access to the device drivers and hence allow `unetbootin` (since it's running as `sudo`) to create a window with nthose steps:

1. Under user run

   ```
   xhost local:root
   ```

   non-network local connections being added to access control list
2. Then with sudo

   ```
   sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 /usr/bin/unetbootin
   ```

Source: https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/issues/94

So you can add an alias to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
 alias unetbootin="xhost local:root && sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 unetbootin"
```

Comment: thx - this worked for me under ubuntu 18.04 deb and ppa did not

Answer (score 0):

Tried the accepted answer above but still had blank screen on Ubuntu 18.04

**What I discovered**: As part of the messages in terminal from `sudo apt-get install unetbootin` I saw the following:

```
Reading package lists... 
Suggested packages:
  p7zip-rar
Recommended packages:
  gksu | kdesudo
```

**My solution:** Install `gksu`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:belin/stable
sudo apt install gksu
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Vouila: Fully functioning UNetbootin screen & app

[image: Fullly functioning UNetbootin screen]

Warning?: I don't know if I understand all the ramifications of installing gksu. There seemed to be MANY update and upgrade dependencies when I installed gksu (all handled nicely by apt). The only thing I've noticed so far since installing gksu is my message windows changed a bit (they look better to me).

Answer (score 0):

I had to create an USB pendrive on Ubuntu 18.04 for Windows 10 install and it needs NTFS, but `unetbootin` GUI can not list NTFS partitions, so I had to use `unetbootin` with command line.

```
xhost local:root

sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 /usr/bin/unetbootin installtype=USB targetdrive=/dev/sdb method=diskimage isofile=/home/peter/Downloads/Win10_2004_Hungarian_x64.iso autoinstall=yes
```