# Ubuntu 18.04: Backslash key incorrectly mapped in ANSI keyboard (English US)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have this exact keyboard, with US ANSI layout:

[image: key1]

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04. In `Region & Language`, Language is defined as English (United States), Formats is United States (English), and the Input Sources is English (US).

All keys seem to map correctly except for the BACKSLASH KEY (`\` and `|`). When I click on the backslash key, it maps to the `<`/`>` (highlighted in red in the photo below) instead of the actual backslash key (highlighted in green).

See the photo I just took to see what happens... I have no way of typing `\` and `|` (in fact I had to copy them from internet to ask this question), which is an absolute disaster.

[image: key2]

How can I solve this??

EDIT:

Running `xev` and pressing the backslash key returns this:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x190, subw 0x0, time 104965, (16,-13), root:(113,89),
    state 0x0, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x190, subw 0x0, time 105084, (16,-13), root:(113,89),
    state 0x0, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The normal slash key is correctly mapped:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0x190, subw 0x0, time 278763, (270,441), root:(367,543),
    state 0x0, keycode 61 (keysym 0x2f, slash), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0x190, subw 0x0, time 278864, (270,441), root:(367,543),
    state 0x0, keycode 61 (keysym 0x2f, slash), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: See my edit fr the xev output

Comment: Apparently my laptop is missing a patch that should have come installed from factory... The company sent the patch in a zip file, but I am not completely sure how to install it, supposedly I should make a bootable usb with the patch, anybody knows how?

Comment: `xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = backslash"` gives me a blank output, literally nothing, I get the prompt on the next line. They did give me a small tutorial, but when I follow the steps and try to boot from the usb with the patch, I get `This is not a bootable disk. Please insert a bootable floppy and press any key to try again...`

Comment: Yes, after running the `xmodmap` command, it types `\`, but not `|`, and this is not mantained after reboot. This is the file that they shared with me with the patch: https://slimbook.es/images/descargas/Cedilla_FIX.zip The tutorial is in Spanish, but automatic translation might still make sense: https://slimbook.es/tutoriales/slimbook/274-parche-intel-me-s-000086-para-slimbook-excalibur2 Let me know if you have access

Comment: The tutorial is just: `1-` Install UNetbootin `2-` Format USB in FAT32 `3-` Open UNetbootin and choose FreeDOS version 1.0 and Accept `4-` Copy the uncompressed Cedilla patch files into the USB root `5-` Disable Secure Boot and boot from the USB (I get the error here)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. extract the .zip file provided by supplier.

[image]

2. bring out the sub-folder from Cedilla_FIX and rename it as PAT

[image]

make sure this PAT folder will contain below files.

[image]

3. now install unetbootin with below commands if not yet installed.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install unetbootin`

now we have required folder `PAT` & `unetbootin` software to make the USB bootable.

4. insert the empty USB that we are going to make bootable.
5. format the USB to FAT32 type.
6. open unetbootin `sudo unetbootin`
7. select `FreeDOS` beside the text `Distribution` and proceed with OK.

[image]

8. now the USB became bootable, we need to paste the `PAT` folder in it.

[image]

9. now reboot the system and get into boot menu.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi I am trying this only now... I still see the message "This is not a bootable disk. Please insert a bootable floppy and press any key to try again". I notice that when `unetbooting` completes successfully, I do not have all the files you have in my usb stick... I miss the files `ldlinux.c32` and `ldlinux.sys`

Comment: OK I created the bootable stick in a Mac this time (instead of in Ubuntu as I was doing). I still do not have your files `ldlinux.c32`, `libcom32.c32`, and `libutil.c32`, but I do have `ldlinux.sys`, and this time the usb boots!

Comment: The keys work properly now it seems, but the laptop froze when I rebooted... Let me update you in a bit

Comment: When I create it with Mac, it boots, when I create it with Ubuntu it doesn't... I thought you had used Mac to create it looking at the screenshots

Comment: In Ubuntu, I actually had to run it with `sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 unetbootin` (https://askubuntu.com/questions/776611/unetbootin-has-no-gui-on-ubuntu-gnome), maybe it has something to do with it... but it didn't give me no error or anything, it just didn't boot afterwards

Comment: Then I really have no clue why in my case the usb stick didn't boot and I got the message `This is not a bootable disk. Please insert a bootable floppy and press any key to try again`

Comment: Oh well either way the key seems to be working properly now, I will focus on working on the other problems with my laptop XD