# Swapped backslash key with right alt on MSI laptop

Tags: keyboard-layout

When I type on the built-in keyboard of my MSI laptop GS75 Stealth 9SF, it seems that the mapping of the `backslash` key (`\|`) and the `Right alt` key are swapped.

This issue persists no matter what keyboard layout or language I choose.

Here is what `xev` outputs when I push right Alt:

```
keycode 94 (keysym 0x5c, backslash)
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 51
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5c) "\"
```

And this is the output of me pushing the backslash key:

```
keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift)
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
```

---

When I use external USB keyboard, all works properly as expected, so it seems like the SteelSeries keyboard manufacturer messed up key codes? That's what I've thought at first, but then I've realised that it works properly on Windows.

---

And here is an image of the keyboard layout from [LaptopMag's review](https://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/msi-gs75-stealth):

[image]
<sub>(source: [purch.com](https://img.purch.com/o/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGFwdG9wbWFnLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvdXBsb2Fkcy9wcHJlc3MvNDU3NjkvbXNpLWdzNzUtc3RlYWx0aC0wMDYuanBn))</sub>

It's those two keys that are on the right side of the spacebar.

Comment: Hi.. you can easily swap them using `xmodmap` are you looking for a work around or you want to notice this to MSI? if they have official support for Ubuntu.. they may give you a patch like in this link. https://askubuntu.com/q/1103370/739431

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1175072/739431 may be useful

Comment: Hi, I've already tried to use `xmodmap`, but the thing is that I cannot use Shift + backslash combination to create a bar (`|`). I'm issuing this command: `xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = backslash bar"`. But when I look at the output of `xmodmap -pke`, it shows `keycode 108 = backslash NoSymbol`. Do you have any idea, how could I fix this?

Comment: Btw I've done some basic google search for MSI keyboard patch, but found nothing, so I guess I would have to describe the issue to the MSI support, right? The thing is that according to my experience, their response time is more than 7 days, so I'd prefer faster solution.

Comment: Hi.. 0k.. when you are online let's do some trails to fix this.. its 5:40am here

Comment: Hi,  you didn't mention your OS.. I too didn't ask.. plz edit your Q to include your OS.. based on that I may edit answer also..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my MSI laptop there's a "backslash/alt key swap" option on the BIOS/UEFI setup under the "Advanced" tab. You should have it on "Disabled".

Comment: This is an excellent point, I wouldn't find it myself, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it in my laptop with Right Alt key, which is also 108 keycode for me..

The point I understood from your output is,
your Right Alt key with keycode 108 is having modifier `ISO_Level3_Shift` you can check this to confirm by running simply `xmodmap`

Exmaple:

```
pratap@pratap:~$ xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)

pratap@pratap:~$
```

This means when you combine Right Alt with Shift it should print 4th keysym

So you need to remove the modifier from Right Alt before running

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = backslash bar"
```

To remove the modifier from Right Alt, the best way is to use either `gnome-tweaks` or `gsettings`

Gnome-Tweaks:
[image]

gsettings:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

to set the value to none run below command. [Be careful if you get multiple options from above command]

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation how to swap the keys using GNOME. The thing is that it turned out to be an issue of wrong BIOS settings, which is hardware related, thus better solution was to disable the swap of those keys in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting for "Polish(legacy)" keyboard layout it worked for me

Comment: Polish (legacy) is a keyboard layout