# Software Updater shows one more empty update at the end

Tags: 16.04, update-manager

After each update, Software Updater shows this:

[image: software updater dialog]

Clicking <kbd>install now</kbd> does nothing. I can close this window, but it appears after every update...

Any hints on how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

duplicate of [Invisible updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331680/invisible-updates)
there is also a [bug-report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1211511) 
you can run

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

from a shell to see what packages will be installed and continue from there