# Software Updater is not showing the list of available updates

Tags: apt, updates, lubuntu, 18.04

I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 and my Software Updater shows only the size of the available updates and does not show the list of the updates! It happened many times like so.[image]

I can see the updates list without problems in terminal by using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Do you happen to have GSConnect and kdeconnect installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invisible software updates list in Software Updater](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331680/invisible-software-updates-list-in-software-updater)