# Blank updates in Software Updater in 18.04

Tags: apt, updates, 18.04

I have 18.04 installed, but just recently I noticed my updates are shown as blank and pre-downloaded even though I have configured updates as notifications only. I find this very odd and a little disconcerting, but I'm resigned to the fact that something has probably gone slightly screwy. How to fix this, so that the updater display the updates, or not show up if there is nothing to update?

[image: Blank Updates?]

[image: It's set to notification only!]

Even though there is nothing listed, I can't be certain if anything is being installed, hence I can't help but feel slightly paranoid. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invisible software updates list in Software Updater](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331680/invisible-software-updates-list-in-software-updater)

Answer (score -1):

I put off the update for over a week, it included some primary components, lib kits, etc... *(requires admin)* but mostly (size-wise) was firefox package. I don't use that browser. None the worse for it so far, and the "remind me later" nag notice is gone.