# Invisible software updates list in Software Updater app

Tags: 16.04, updates, update-manager

I've got the updates by launching the Software Updater in Ubuntu 16.04 and they aren't visible (see image).
Rebooting Ubuntu and relaunching the Software Updater still causes the invisible software updates list.

[image: void_update_list]

I found the **solving sequece**:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
*list of packages*
**[Y/n]n**

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

**[Y/n]y**

---

and now **Software Updater** displays the visible list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invisible updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331680/invisible-updates)